# Probability that the sum of two integers randomly picked from a range of [0;150] will be less or equal to 256?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability that the sum of two integers randomly picked from a range of $[0;150]$ will be less or equal to 256? Integers can be the same. This includes 0 and 150 and must be a real integer

Comment: Also worth asking, must these numbers be integers?  Or are you picking real numbers from the interval?  Are they picked uniformly and independently at random?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Yes, these numbers must be integers and yes, they picked uniformly and independently at random.

Comment: @Yay: Yep,  I include 0 and 150.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to approach this is to imagine a lattice of the possible points.  Here it is $151 \times 151$.  You are then trying to count the points below or on the line $x+y=256$  It is slightly easier to count the ones above the line and subtract because you just have a right isosceles triangle.  If you draw a picture, you should be able to convince yourself that the points above the line are $1+2+3+4+\ldots 44=\frac 12\cdot 44 \cdot 45$ because there are $44$ points on each leg of the triangle, corresponding to one number being $150$ and the other $107-150$.  The chance is then $$1-\frac {44\cdot 45}{2\cdot 151^2}=\frac {21811}{22801}\approx 0.9566$$

Answer (score 1):

Are you okay with the idea of adding conditional probalities with conditions are indepent.

For example: if there is a 75% chance of rain and if it rains there is a 10% chance I'll take a walk.  And if it doesn't rain there is a 60% chance I'll take a walk. Then the chance that it rains and I take a walk is the probability of rain times the probability of a walk give it rains.  ($0.75 \times 0.1 = 0.075$). And the probability of it doesn't rain and I take a walk is the probabily of no rain, times the probability of a walk given no rain. ($0.25\times 0.6 = 0.15$).  As the event of rain and not rain are mutually exclusive we can add those probabilities.  ($0.075 + 0.15 = 0.225$) so the probability that I take a walk is 22.5%.

Are you okay with that.

So if for your first number, $a$ you pick anything equal to or less than $a \le 256-150 = 106$ then the probability that your second number will make a sum less or equal to $256$ is a certainty; $100\%$.  That is if $a \le 106$ and $a + b \le a + 150 \le 106 + 150 = 256$.  That is a certainty.

So the probability of the first being less or equal to $106$ is: There are $151$ choices for the first number ($0$ through $150$); and there are $107$ ways the number is $\le 106$ (it may be $0... 106$.) So the probability of your first number being less or equal to $106$ is $\frac {107}{151}$.  And *IF* that occured to probability of you second number being $150$ or less to make the sum $256$ or less is $1$.  It must happen.

So the probability that 1) your first number is $\le 106$ and 2) the sum of your numbers is $\le 256$ is:  $\frac {107}{151} \times 1=\frac {107}{151}$.

Now if instead you first number was $a$ and $a > 106$.  The for you sum $a +b \le 256$, we muat have $b \le 256 -a$.  So $b$ can be anything from $0$ to $256 -a$.  There are $257-a$ possible ways this can happen so *IF* your first number is $a$ then the probability that the second number, $b$, is $\le 256-a$ is $\frac {257-a}{151}$.

And the probability that the first number is $a$ is $\frac 1{151}$.  So the probability that your first number is $a$ *and* your second number is $\le 256 a$ is: $\frac 1{151}\cdot \frac {257-a}{151}$.

So if you add all thes probabilities toger you get:

Probability sum is $256$ or less $= \frac {107}{151} + \sum\limits_{a=107}^{150}  \frac 1{151}\frac{257-a}{151}=$

$\frac {107}{151} + \frac 1{151^2}\sum\limits_{a=107}^{150} (257-a)$

So what is $\sum\limits_{a=107}^{150} (257-a)$?

Well it is $\sum_{a=107}^{150}257 + \sum_{a=107}^{150} a$.

And $\sum_{a=107}^{150} 257 = 257 + 257 +...+257 = 257(150-106) = 257*44$.

And $\sum_{a=107}^{150} a = (1 + 2+ 3 +....... + 150) - (1+2+3+...... + 106)= $

$\frac {150*151}2 - \frac {106*107}2 = 75*151 - 53*107$.

So $\sum\limits_{a=107}^{150} (257-a) = 257*44- 75*151 + 53*107$

And the probality we want is:

$\frac {107}{151} + \frac 1{151^2}(257*44 - 75*151 + 53*107)=$

$\frac {107 + \frac {257*44+53*107}{151} - 75}{151}=$

$\frac {32 +\frac {257*44+53*107}{151} }{151}=$

$\frac {144\frac {67}{151}}{151} \approx 95.7\%$.